# How to evaluate a flow When Record is created OR a specific field gets changed and Update a Parent Object

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I'm using a flow that runs when Record is Created or Record is Updated but I'm having issues running it for both of the cases(When I get a new record OR when I update the Owner on an existing record).It is either one or the other.

I want to run the flow if the Record is New BUT also want to run the flow IF the Record Owner gets changed.

I can't use the before save option, because I want to update the Parent Account and in the before save operation you can't update records aside from the triggering records.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What part isn't working?  Please edit your question with more details, including screenshots of your current flow setup so we can understand which part of this you're stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

Or(
ISNEW(),
ISCHANGED (OWNERID)
)

Something like that formula would be needed in the trigger of the flow. At least that is what I am thinking I need to work on doing for my workflows to help cut down the number of changes running when an update occurs to the opportunity.